# I am stuck with some details when graphing this function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

> Let $f(x) = \frac{x^3 + 1}{x}. $ Plot the function using derivatives criteria.

First of all, $f$ is indeterminate at $x=0.$ So I would have to deal with 2 intervals, separately: $(- \infty, 0)$, and $(0, \infty)$.

I would also have to consider:

$\lim_{\to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} + x^2 = 0 + \infty = \infty$

$\lim_{\to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{\to -\infty} \frac{1}{x} + x^2 = 0 + (-\infty)^2 = \infty$

If $x\neq 0,   \frac{x^3 + 1}{x} = 0 \implies x^3 + 1 = 0,$ so the only root in $\mathbb{R}$ is $x=-1.$

If $x>0, \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x^3 + 1}{x} = ( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} ) ( \lim_{x \to 0} x^3 + 1) = (\infty)(1) = \infty $

And if  $x <0, \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x^3 + 1}{x} = ( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} ) ( \lim_{x \to 0} x^3 + 1) = (-\infty)(1) = -\infty $

Then $f '(x) = \frac{2x^3 -1}{x^2}$

It should happen that, at $(\infty, 0)$, $f$ is decreasing. And $x<0 \implies 2x^3 -1 < 0 \implies \frac{2x^3 -1}{x^2} < 0.$ So $f'(x) < 0 \implies f$ is decreasing at $(-\infty, 0)$

and it should also happen that, at $(0, \infty)$, the function is increasing.

But, if $x<0$, it doesn't neccessarily happen that $2x^3 -1 > 0,$ So I am stuck here. However if i could assume that $2x^3 -1 > 0, $ then $f '(x) = \frac{2x^3 -1}{x^2} > 0,$ so $f$ would be increasing.

To find critical points, $f '(x) = \frac{2x^3 -1}{x^2} = 0 \implies_{x \neq 0} x =  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},$ or $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} ,$ and $f''(x) = \frac{2x^3+2}{x^3},$ so $f''(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}) = 4(\frac{1}{2} + 1) = 6 >0,$ that would mean that $f$ has a local minimum. So my last question is why doesn't $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}
$, the other critical point appears in the graph?

Comment: Why do you say that the function should be increasing on $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: Just curiosity: I find the notation $(\infty, 0)$ somewhat strange and confusing. I thought that the first occurrence of it in your question was a typo, but you repeat it more times. Does not your teacher write $(-\infty, 0)$ instead?

Comment: You've made a mistake finding $f''(x)$, please doble-check

Comment: @Théophile yea I should get both $f'<0 $ and $f'>0 $ in $(0,\infty) $ cause if $f'<0$ Then f is decreasing, and if $f'>0$ then f is increasing

Comment: @ajotaxe I meant that, yes. I  edited the question

Comment: Rights, so $f$ is decreasing then increasing on $(0,\infty)$. Consider also that you had already calculated $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, which tells you that $f$ can't be increasing on the whole interval.

Comment: $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ is not a critical point.  Look again.

Comment: $2x^3-1=0$ has a single solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A qualitative approach.**

The function can be written as $x^2+\dfrac1x$, and is the sum of a parabola and an equilateral hyperbola.

The hyperbola has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ and the horizontal asymptote $y=0$. Hence for small $|x|$ it is dominant, and for large $|x|$, it is neglectible and the function gets closer and closer to the parabola.

In the negatives, both functions are decreasing and the sum is decreasing (to $-\infty$).

In the positives we sum increasing and decreasing and we cannot conclude about the variation. The first derivative is $2x-\dfrac1{x^2}$, which has a single positive root, hence the function has a single minimum.

This is confirmed by a plot:

[image]